# Problematic characters in file path in pandoc

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I'm trying to generate an html output using Rmarkdown notebook. In one place I'm trying to insert an image with the code like this:

````
# my chunk
```{r results='asis'}
cat("![](", image_path, "))
````

The problem is when the `img_path` contains `#` character, e.g. `/tmp/U10_LTC7803EUD#PBF/myimage.png`

In this case I get the following error:

```
[WARNING] Could not fetch resource 
pandoc.exe: /tmp/U10_LTC7803EUD: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Apparently pandoc treats the `#` sign as a comment or something like that and it stops reading the full path terminating it on the problematic character. Is there a way to solve this by pandoc configuration? My problem is that I never know what the path will be since it comes from an external source. Any workaround suggestions are also welcome :)

Comment: You probably need to `quote` the path or escape the character. You could try to replace `#` with `\#`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. What exactly do You mean by `qoute`? Adding extra quotation marks around `image_path` variable or something else? Quotation marks don't work

Comment: I don't think the problem is with Pandoc. Pandoc will convert `![]( my/path/with#in.png )` into `<p><img src="my/path/with#in.png" /></p>`. I think the issue is in your R code.

Comment: @RaniereSilva I don't think the problem is with R code because when I execute chunks one by one everything works fine. The problem appears when I try to knit the document. And as the console output shows it is pandoc who complains on the wrong path which is truncated

Answer (score 0):

My workaround solution was to substitute problematic chars so the file paths are clean.